# Limiting a foreach to show only 10 rows of data?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Okay, I have run into a little issue.

I know a bit about PHP/JSON arrays, but WAY more about SQL.

I am using a foreach statement to iterate over this array, but how can I limit it to only show 10 of the results?

```
$Address = $RPC2->getaddressesbyaccount($_SESSION['email']); 

foreach($Address as $Another) {
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

It works fine but when there's 10+ results it messes up the CSS on the page.

How can I make it only show 10 results?

Answer (score 7):

if getaddressesbyaccount returns array you can do it as:

```
foreach(array_slice($Address, 0, 10) as $Another) {
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can break the loop

```
$i = 0;
foreach($Address as $Another) {
    $i++;
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
    if($i==10) break;
}
```

But it's not the cleanest solution.

If your `$Address` array has numeric keys, you can use a for loop instead :

```
$nb = sizeof($Address) < 10 ? sizeof($Address) : 10;
for($i = 0; $i < $nb; $i++){
    echo '<b>' . $Address[$i] . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

`min()` function is used here in case your $Address array's length were less than 10.

Comment: This will loop to **11 items NOT 10**! See my solution (identical), except mine correctly outputs to 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the mistake, I didn't tested code. Edited. But please stop to cry about getting your answers selected.

Comment: There's no crying to have my answers selected. SO is about providing correct, accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could count and break out of the `foreach()`, but why not just:

```
for($i=0; $i<10 && $i<=count($Address); $i++) {
    echo '<b>' . $Address[$i] . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Assuming numeric keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite easily use a `for` loop for this:

```
$Address = $RPC2->getaddressesbyaccount($_SESSION['email']); 

$loopTo = min(count($Address), 10);
for($i = 0; $i < $loopTo; $i++)
{
    echo '<b>'.$Address[$i].'</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `array_slice` variant is a good general-purpose solution because it strikes a good balance between convenience (only one expression to type, allows you to use `foreach` naturally) and genericity (does not depend on the array keys being sequential integers).

However, if you wanted to take a bigger slice out of the original array then `array_slice` would allocate all the slice up front, consuming memory. Since that's not required if all you need is to iterate, a better alternative would be [`LimitIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php):

```
foreach (new LimitIterator($Address, 0, 10) as $Another) {
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for your case

```
foreach(array_slice($Address, 0, 10) as $Another) {
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a key to the `foreach` to get the array indexes. Then terminate the loop when it reaches 10.

```
foreach($Address as $i => $Another) {
    if ($i == 10) {
        break;
    }
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```

Or use `array_slice()` to get just the first 10 elements of the array:

```
foreach(array_slice($Address, 0, 10) as $Another) {
    echo '<b>' . $Another . '</b><br /><br />';
}
```